# Read text file within a .NET project

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

Is there a way I can open and read a text file within a .NET project? I know I can use the System.IO.StreamReader class to do it for a Windows text file.

I'd like to store some SQL scripts for upgrading my database in text files within my project. Since I'm writing this in VB I can't just paste the scripts directly into my code due to line continuations, where I could if it were C#. These are very long scripts.

Comment: Why not just create a stored procedure for each long script?

Comment: Have you thought about turning those scripts into stored procedures?

Comment: So what is the question, since you do know about StreamReader?

Comment: I think his issue is that these scripts will be used to update a database for the application, as such, won't be in the database and could be supplied ad-hoc. I'm just not sure what difference he sees between a text file and a Windows text file.

Comment: By text file vx. Windows text file I was trying to deliniate between a text file and a text file embedded in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Text files inside a project are not added to your executable.  You can enable `Copy to Output Directory` in the properties for the .sql file.  This will copy them alongside your assemblies to the `bin` directory.

From there, your program could read them like any other file.

Answer (score 1):

Embed as resources in the assembly, then use `ResourceManager` to read them into a `Stream` or `String` at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use embedded resources and use a StreamReader on the stream returned by [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) to read those.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem myself.
I can see that Jeff accepted the solution where you copy out the sourcefiles into your project folder.

I however am not comfortable having db-create/drop/alter scripts lying around on fileareas. I found this question was asked again later on. Here is what [solution I implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213) using imbedded resources to great success.

Our solution involves distributed databases spread over possibly several database instances. We implemented a solution that includes a master database containing all setupinformation of the 'shard'-databases. Having a 'SqlUpdate'-engine we can keep all the distributed shards up to date.